# В каких ситуациях вещественной машинной арифметики не выполняются законы ассоциативности и дистрибутивности в C, C++?

Tags: c++, c, погрешность

Есть законы ассоциативности:
(х + у) + z = x + (y + z) и (x * y) * z = x * (y * z).
Также есть закон дистрибутивности:
(х + у) * z = x * z + y * z.
В вещественной машинной арифметике данные законы выполняются не во всех случаях. В каких именно случаях это происходит? Если это связано со значениями переменных, то при каких значениях законы не будут выполняться? Желательно с примерами на языке.

Comment: `1e9 + 1e-9 == 1e9` https://godbolt.org/z/MvsWr7W9o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Математические законы выполняются всегда. А вот указанные вами равенства могут не выполняться, только это не имеет никакого отношения к математическим законам - здесь имеет значение формат хранения чисел в памяти машины. Также это относится не только к арифметике вещественных чисел.
Так, при любых операциях может быть переполнение числа. Например, если у вас тип данных беззнаковый 8-битный `unsigned char` то максимальное число которое в нем можно хранить - 255. И тогда равенство `(250 + 7) - 3 = 250 + (7 - 3)` не выполнится, т.к. в левой части произойдет переполнение а в правой - нет.
При операциях с вещественными числами компьютерный формат хранения не позволяет выразить любое число - числа хранятся с округлением. Так, к примеру число 0,2 в вещественной переменной `float` будет хранится как 0,200000003. Или прибавление маленьких чисел к большим числам не меняет результат - например `1e22 + 1 == 1e22`. Ну или как написал AlexGlebe `1e9 + 1e-9 == 1e9`. Потому что прибавляемое число меньше погрешности, с которой хранится первое число. Из-за этого могут как-бы "не выполняться"  свойства операций - ассоциативности и дистрибутивности. Например `(1e22 - 1e22) + 1 == 1` a `1e22 - (1e22 - 1) == 0`.
Обо всем этом рассказывается в книгах и курсах по "Data Science" (на русском - наука о данных), также в интернете. Например [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/112953/)

Comment: Не хотелось бы портить эффект, но даже строго математически `(1e22 - 1e22) + 1` не равно `1e22 - (1e22 + 1)` :) Вы бы знак поменяли перед единицей...

Comment: @Harry спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Арифметика `unsigned char` всегда соблюдает ассоциативность и дистрибутивность. Это арифметика по модулю, переполнения не мешают.